# How to implement safe read and write operations from multiple users on nodeJs server using MySQL to avoid inconsistency state?

Tags: mysql, node.js, typescript, thread-safety, consistency

I know that nodeJs architecture is based on single Thread and It is  event-driven model. In fact directly on nodeJs App we don't have to care about concurrent writing and reading on a same variable (Tell me if I'm wrong). But I want to know now what about concurrent access on a database row (MySQL) which exchange with a nodeJs App. So how can I implement a consistency state on my App. 
PS : some code examples will be nice. 
Thanks

How to implement safe read and write operations (basic increment a value for exemple)  from multiple users on nodeJs server using MySQL as database to avoid inconsistency state?

Answer (score 1):

Database consistency is all about how the RDBMS implements [Atomicity, Consistency, Isolation, and Duration (ACID).](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID_(computer_science)) It's a different matter from concurrency within a node.js program.

If you want to increment a value in a row in a database table, you can use this query to the database.

```
 UPDATE statistics SET counter = counter + 1 WHERE item = 'someItemId';
```

You need to issue the query from the appropriate method call in your node.js MySQL API.

Even if many different node.js (or Java, or php, or whatever) programs run this kind of query simultaneously on the database, the results will still be consistent. The RDBMS implicitly wraps this kind of query in a [transaction](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-syntax-transactions.html), ensuring it runs to completion once it starts. That's what RDBMS consistency is all about.

A detailed explanation of ACID is far beyond the scope of a Stack Overflow answer.

Comment: *"It's a different matter from concurrency within a node.js program."* Well reusing MySQL connections which you used before to insert for example from the Node.js MySQL library connection pool would still maintain there `LAST_INSERT_ID()` which can also could possibly cause a inconsistent concurrency state If you could call it like that? ...

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your point. Referencing `LAST_INSERT_ID()` before doing an insert on a connection is rather like accessing unitialized memory in an old-school programming language: a completely avoidable programmer error.

Comment: *"I'm not sure I understand your point"* imagine if you make a connection pool you connect you insert but never close the connection .. So the connection keeps alive on the MySQL server.. in thoery MySQL the connection keeps alive with the  `LAST_INSERT_ID()`.. Later you reuse that connection again the `LAST_INSERT_ID()` should still exist within that connection.

Comment: *" Referencing LAST_INSERT_ID() before doing an insert on a connection is rather like accessing unitialized memory in an old-school programming language: a completely avoidable programmer error. "* i agree on that one a problem is it isn't unitialized memory in case off connection pooling

Comment: Model ACID is realized by transactions. Just use it. Other problem is writing code, who realize ACID without transactions. Eg try don't use data from select in update.